# String empty to null custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

Based on this answer [Knockout.js: time input format and value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395946/knockout-js-json-has-numeric-but-knockout-changes-it-to-string-any-suggestions), i'm trying to create a custom binding that sets observable to null if the value is string empty, here is the code that's not working, Ip observable is always null on model

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stringEmptyNull = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor();
            var interceptor = ko.dependentObservable({
                read: underlyingObservable,
                write: function (value) {
                    if (value != null && value.trim() == '')
                        underlyingObservable();
                }
            });
            ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function () { return interceptor }, allBindingsAccessor);
        },
        update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
    };
```

input:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="stringEmptyNull: Ip" />
```

Model:

```
var Model = function () {
        this.Ip = ko.observable()
        ko.applyBindings(this, $myForm[0]);
    };

    instance = new Model();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is in your `interceptor`.

In your `write` function you need to set the `underlyingObservable` to `null` when the `value` is an empty string (calling only `underlyingObservable();` only gets its value but does not set its value to `null`)
and you also need to pass `value` to `underlyingObservable` in every other case:

```
var interceptor = ko.dependentObservable({
    read: underlyingObservable,
    write: function (value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim() == '')
            underlyingObservable(null);
        else
            underlyingObservable(value);
    }
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/LLQVe/). (Open your browser's console then type something in the textbox and then clear the textbox)