# numeric observable not working with knockout validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I'm using a custom observable, `numericObservable`, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396039/791406), which forces knockout to serialize numeric fields as numbers in json, not strings; I've got that part working.

I've added validation to enforce `number` as the field type for port:

```
 self.port = ko.numericObservable(22).extend({ number: true });
```

..but validation is not working 100%. It seems to pick up non-numerics sometimes, other times it just fails to recognize. If I clear the value for port, switch focus to another field, then come back and enter a number, it works.

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/q4QCY/13/

If I use validation against a plain observable, like below, it works, so I suspect the issue may be with extending `numericObservable`. Also, the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RJbdS/) from which I got `numericObservable` uses `ko 2.2.2`, my fiddle uses `ko 3.0.0`.

```
//works
self.port = ko.observable(22).extend({ number: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `parseFloat` function just ignores non numeric symbols. Your code line must use "+" to avoid this:

```
var parsedValue = parseFloat(+newValue);
```

Comment: upon further anaylsis, this is working. I switched to `parseInt(+newValue)`, don't need floats. Im doing some additional testing to make sure the validation is working, ty